# How to get TextBox ClientID in a javascript function using ListView and InsertTamplate or EditTemplate

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ListView with ItemTemplate, EditTemplate and InsertTemplate.
There are several TextBoxes in Edit and InsertTemplate. I need to calculate some of the values in Javascript, but I don't know, how to get a ClientID in my JS function or pass it as a parameter.

Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
        var length = document.getElementById('???').value;
        var quantity = document.getElementById('???').value;
        var fullLength = document.getElementById('???');
        fullLength.value = length*quantity;
    }
</script>
```

ASP.NET piece of my ListView:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Weight" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Weight") %>' />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Quantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Quantity") %>' />
    <asp:TextBox ID="FullLength" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FullLength") %>' />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Insert" Text="AddNewEntry" CommandName="Insert" OnClientClick="calculate()" />
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

What sould be instead of '???'?
Or, can I pass it somehow in the parameters in the OnClientClick="calculate(???,???,???)"?

Thanks in advance, JiKra

Answer (score 0):

Now that asp.net supports ClientIDMode "predictable" you can do this by adding an OnClientClick handler for the update button in the EditItemTemplate.

- Set the ListView's ClientIDMode to predictable.
- Set the ListView's ClientIDRowSuffix to the primary key for the row (e.g., ProductID for Northwind's Products table)
- Pass the product ID to the OnClientClick handler
- use document.getElementById to get the current value of the field.

For example, let's say you have ListView1 bound to Northwind's Products table. The primary key for Products is ProductID. The declarative syntax for the ListView is:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ClientIDMode="Predictable" 
        ClientIDRowSuffix="ProductID">
```

The EditItemTemplate's Update button's declarative syntax is:

```
<asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                        Text="Update" OnClientClick=<%# string.Format("ShowProductName('{0}');", Eval("ProductID")) %> />
```

And the OnClientClick handler javascript is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProductName(prodId) {
        var prodNameTextBox = document.getElementById('ListView1_ProductNameTextBox_' + prodId);

        alert('product name is ' + prodNameTextBox.value);

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Note: Assumes that the product name is stored in a textbox named ProductNameTextBox. Change that to match the name of the textbox with the field you want. Predictable mode will result in an ID along the lines of ListView1_YOURFIELDNAMEHERE_PRODUCTIDHERE.

For details, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410598(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I don't know, how to emit javascript function in the C# code. Could you provide a piece of code or link to a related article, please?