# Javascript to set label value in asp.net listview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net listview with a column that contains 2 buttons, a textbox and label.

When a button is clicked a javascript function is executed.

This function takes the value in the textbox and then starts a count down in the label.

Problem is, no matter what row I select, it takes the value from first row of the listview and sets the label in the first row of the listview also.

I have made dozens of attempts to get this to work, but can't get it to use the right row.

How can I make sure it gets and sets the correct values?

Thank you

```
function countdown() {
      interval = setInterval(function () {
          var lbl = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctrl0_lblCountDown");
          var txt = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctrl0_txtTimeMinutes");


  <asp:Button ID="buttStartTimer" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:countdown()" Text="Start" />
  <asp:Button ID="buttStopTimer" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:stopcountdown()" Text="Stop" />
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTimeMinutes" Text='<%#Eval("FormulaTiming")%>'></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Label ID="lblCountDown" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

## Other Attempts

```
  <%--<input type="button" onclick='countdown()'; value="Start" id="Start" />
  <input type="button" onclick='stopcountdown()'; value="Stop" id="Stop" />--%>
  <%--<input type="button" onclick='countdown(this.form.TimeMinutes, this.form.spCountDown)'; value="Start" id="Start" />
   <input type="button" onclick='stopcountdown()'; value="Stop" id="Stop" />--%>
  <%-- <input type="button" onclick='<%# Eval("FormulaTiming", "countdown({0});")%>' value="Start" id="Button2" />
  <input type="button" onclick='stopcountdown()'; value="Stop" id="Button3" />--%>
  <%--<input type="text" value='<%#Eval("FormulaTiming")%>' id="txtTimeMinutes" />--%>
```

Comment: I think you are missing some of your JS in the top code block.

Comment: Yes, I only put the first part where it gets a reference to the controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use jquery instead:

Give all of the buttons a class and then use jquery to find that class:

```
$(".myButtonClass").click(function() {
    var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
    var listViewRowID = buttonID.substring(buttonID.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
    updateLabel("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstViewFormulas_ctr"+listViewRowID+"_lblCountDown")
}
```

Then just write your updateLabel command to update the input label

Please note, this has not been tested (just off the top of my head)

Comment: So I wouldn't have to worry about the row?

Comment: The listViewRowID should get the listview row number.  Then you would use that to find your label id.

Comment: Here is another method that you can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176536/how-to-get-textbox-clientid-in-a-javascript-function-using-listview-and-insertta?rq=1

Comment: Do I assign all of the controls I will be using the same cssclass?  Like cssClass="countdown"?

Comment: set all of the buttons to the myButtonClass